# Objective-C call to GetList webservice on SharePoint 2010 returning no data

Tags: objective-c, web-services, sharepoint, get

Just starting to get my feet wet with Web Services calls to SharePoint(2010) and making calls like `GetWebCollection` and `GetListCollection` are working correctly and returning the expected data. Running the `GetListCollection` returns all the SP Lists as expected.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetListCollection xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" />
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

From the SP Lists returned, I extract the Internal Name for the Calendar list {A2CEBD3C-D07A-44A3-BE34-975AFE57F56C}

```
<_sList>
    <InternalName>{A2CEBD3C-D07A-44A3-BE34-975AFE57F56C}</InternalName>
    <Title>Calendar</Title>
    …..
```

My problem comes when I try to make a `GetList` call with that ID value as:

```
NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                        "<soap:Body>\n"
                        "<GetList xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\" />\n"
                        "<listName>{A2CEBD3C-D07A-44A3-BE34-975AFE57F56C}</listName>\n"
                        "</GetList>\n"
                        "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>\n"];


    NSLog(@"Request is : %@",soapFormat);

    NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.114/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"];

    NSLog(@"Web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];


    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList"
                            forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

When I run this in the iPad 5.1 Simulator, the `GetList` call authenticates and connects, but returns 0 bytes back.

```
2013-01-05 13:31:56.053 SoapSharePoint[1936:c07] Request is : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" />
<listName>{A2CEBD3C-D07A-44A3-BE34-975AFE57F56C}</listName>
</GetList>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
2013-01-05 13:31:56.055 SoapSharePoint[1936:c07] Web url = http://192.168.0.114/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
2013-01-05 13:31:56.059 SoapSharePoint[1936:c07] Connected...
2013-01-05 13:31:56.136 SoapSharePoint[1936:c07] Received Auth Req.
2013-01-05 13:31:56.147 SoapSharePoint[1936:c07] Received 0 Bytes!
2013-01-05 13:31:56.147 SoapSharePoint[1936:c07]
```

Using Fiddler and using U2U CAML Query Builder on another workstation I can see the U2U product issues a `GetListCollection`, `GetAllSubWebCollections` when it starts up (knows all sites and lists now) and when I double-click on the Calendar list they send this `SOAP` request:

```
POST http://g2010/_vti_bin/lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.5466)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList"
Host: g2010
Content-Length: 378
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>{A2CEBD3C-D07A-44A3-BE34-975AFE57F56C}</listName>
</GetList>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This returns the List fields, and allows me to build a `CAML` query which then returns the 2 items in the Calendar list. I'm not seeing why MY call to `GetList` is not returning any data and was hoping someone could spot my obvious error :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This explanation might be a little overkill, but rather this than unclear. Your `GetList` tag ends prematurely in your code block.

```
<GetList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" />
    <listName>{A2CEBD3C-D07A-44A3-BE34-975AFE57F56C}</listName>
</GetList>
```

The last / on the first GetList tag makes sure that `GetList` is closed immediately. Writing `<GetList />` is the same as writing `<GetList></GetList>`. So your codeblock is seen as:

```
<GetList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" >
</GetList>
<listName>{A2CEBD3C-D07A-44A3-BE34-975AFE57F56C}</listName>
</GetList>
```

In which the first two lines are one `GetList` without listName, the third line is a listName but has no `GetList` around it anymore and the fourth line is an "end of GetList" tag that does nothing.

Removing the last / out of your first `GetList` tag should make everything work :-)